# Kate Winthrop's ability stops monsters from appearing at midnight?

Tags: elder-sign

Mythos card revealing happens inside the player's turn? So Kate's ability stops monsters from appearing or the players turn starts after the mythos card reveal? Also do you progress the clock before or after you reveal a new adventure card, so is there a case where you get a new adventure with a midnight effect and you must immediately activate it ?